# How implement scrollable and zoomable Line Graph in Ios

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Hi I am trying to implement line chart. Chart having following features:
=> it has scrollable features.
=> it should be zoomable.
chart should be zoomable like that
if x axis having value week1 week2 so on ... and if zoom the graph it become scrollable and value of x axis becomes 1,2,3,4,5,6 . values becomes 1,2,3.... on the tapped places.

=> and also i want to show x and y value of tapped point.

I trying to google a lot but unable to Find such library where I got exact Solution of my problem. I have invested more than two days.
Any buddy found right solution of my problem please guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at [Core Plot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot)? It can do what you want. It includes several example apps to get you started. If you have specific questions, ask them here on StackOverflow and use the [`core-plot`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/core-plot) tag.